# How to easily iterate over all super classes/interfaces

Tags: java, iteration, breadth-first-search

What is the most elegant way to iterate over all super classes/interfaces of a given `Class<?>` object? I am basically looking for a recursive [`getSuperclass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass()) and [`getInterfaces()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getInterfaces()) method, collecting the whole class hierarchy.

Lets assume our inheritance looks like follows (where `Cn` are classes and `In` are interfaces):

```
         I3
        ↗  ↖
C2    I1    I2
  ↖     ↖  ↗
   C1    I0
     ↖  ↗ 
      C0
```

It should catch all classes displayed above. If possible, the iteration order should be [breadth first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), so something like this:

```
C0 -> C1 -> I0 -> C2 -> I1 -> I2 -> I3
```

Is there a built in method or a library providing creating a `Collection<Class<?>>`, `Stream<Class<?>>` or an `Iterator<Class<?>>`?

Any help is appretiated.

Comment: You are performing reflection.  That means that elegant solutions are no longer possible.

Comment: No, you'll have to use reflection and build your own implementation, based on your preferred algorithm.

Comment: Is `C1` the "highest" super-class in your diagram ? Or is it `I4` ?

Comment: @c0der inheritance in uml diagrams usually uses arrows to point to the super class. So `C0` (just changed the indexing) is the lowest in the hierarchy

Comment: I thought so, I find the numbers confusing (expected 0 to be the base). Also `C2->I1` doesn't make sense to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you already seem to use Guava, here's a solution using Guava's Graph Traversal utilities.

```
public static Iterable<Class<?>> getClassHierarchy(Class<?> baseClass) {

    return Traverser.forGraph(
        (SuccessorsFunction<Class<?>>) node -> {
            Class<?> superclass = node.getSuperclass();
            List<Class<?>> interfaces = Arrays.asList(node.getInterfaces());
            return superclass == null ? interfaces
                : Iterables.concat(interfaces, Collections.singleton(superclass));
        }
    ).breadthFirst(baseClass);
}
```

Comment: Now this is a truly beautiful answer :)

Answer (score 3):

This solution implements an `Iterator<Class<?>>`. If you are OK with using libraries, I would recommend checking out [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49862841/4298200).

```
public static class HierarchyIterator implements Iterator<Class<?>> {
    private Queue<Class<?>> remaining = new LinkedList<>();
    private Set<Class<?>> visited = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    public HierarchyIterator(Class<?> initial) {
        append(initial);
    }

    private void append(Class<?> toAppend) {
        if (toAppend != null && !visited.contains(toAppend)) {
            remaining.add(toAppend);
            visited.add(toAppend);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return remaining.size() > 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> next() {
        if (!hasNext()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        Class<?> polled = remaining.poll();
        append(polled.getSuperclass());
        for (Class<?> superInterface : polled.getInterfaces()) {
            append(superInterface);
        }
        return polled;
    }
}
```

If you need a `Collection<Class<?>>`, you can use [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) for:

```
public static Set<Class<?>> getClassHierarchy(Class<?> forClass) {
    Set<Class<?>> result = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    Iterators.addAll(result, new HierarchyIterator(forClass));
    return result;
}
```

calling:

```
System.out.println(getClassHierarchy(LinkedList.class));
```

yields

```
[class java.util.LinkedList, class java.util.AbstractSequentialList, interface java.util.List, interface java.util.Deque, interface java.lang.Cloneable, interface java.io.Serializable, class java.util.AbstractList, interface java.util.Collection, interface java.util.Queue, class java.util.AbstractCollection, interface java.lang.Iterable, class java.lang.Object]
```

Comment: Design notes: a) calling append on classes retrieved from the queue is messy, I'd prefer a solution that calls getSuperClass() and getInterfaces() exactly once per class. b) it's more elegant to create a reusable Iterable rather than an Iterator. That said, I tried to come up with a solution like that and it would have been significantly more complicated, so this seems like a pretty good solution after all.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd @a&b: yes, I fully agree! That is why I didn't accept my own answer

Answer (score 3):

I take your question more or less like a game, and I noticed that the *breadth first* requirement is not mandatory, so here is my solution.

1. It uses reflection.
2. It uses recursion.
3. It uses functional programming.
4. It is not very long.
5. It implements an internal iterator - `forEach` style.
6. You need Java 9 to compile it.
7. It is just a programming game :)

---

```
public class ClassIterator {
    public void forEachSuperclasses(final Class<?> initialClass, final Consumer<Class<?>> action) {
        generateStream(initialClass).distinct().forEach(action);
    }

    private Stream<Class<?>> generateStream(final Class<?> clazz) {
        if (clazz == null) {
            return Stream.empty();
        }
        return Stream.concat(
               Stream.concat(Stream.of(clazz), generateStream(clazz.getSuperclass())),
                    Arrays.stream(clazz.getInterfaces()).flatMap(this::generateStream));
    }
}
```

How to call it:

```
interface I3 {};
class C2 implements I3 {};
interface I1 extends I3 {};
interface I2 {};
class C1 extends C2 {};
interface I0 extends I0, I0 {};
class C0 extends C1 implements I0 {};

void testForEachSuperclasses() {
    final ClassIterator iterator = new ClassIterator();
    iterator.forEachSuperclasses(C1.class, System.out::println);
}
```

Output:

```
class com.example.classiterator.C0
class com.example.classiterator.C1
class com.example.classiterator.C2
class java.lang.Object
interface com.example.classiterator.I3
interface com.example.classiterator.I0
interface com.example.classiterator.I1
interface com.example.classiterator.I2
```

Comment: It is a fun solution, but it is debatable if its "elegant" ;)

Comment: some critique: you shouldn't call your class `ClassIterator` if it's not an `Iterator`. Giving the user access only to the method taking a `Consumer<Class<?>>` seems weird. Why don't you expose the `Stream<Class<?>>`?

Comment: I find it an elegant (non DFS) solution

Comment: @c0der how is that related to this answer?

Comment: I meant "i find it an elegant (non BFS) solution". It relates to "If possible, the iteration order should be breadth first" in the post.

Comment: @c0der well, creating that many `Stream`s does hurt a bit. I tested it against my own solution and it takes roughly 5* as long with `LinkedList.class`. And then there are the two things I mentioned ;)

Comment: @LonelyNeuron: Why is the name wrong? "An *iterator* is an object that enables a programmer to traverse a container" - and that is *exactly* what this object does. It implements *internal* iteration, not external, that's the only difference. And giving the method access only to the `Consumer<>` is the point in internal iteration - you completely delegate the burden of iteration to the object and pass only the *action* to be performed on each element.

Comment: @HonzaZidek yes, but in Java, an `Iterator` is quite a well known class. If I ever use a library and see a class called `FooIterator<Bar>` I will call it like `Iterator<Bar> iter = new FooIterator<Bar>()`. Your code would not compile and I would be mad forever.

Comment: Just a few examples from Java runtime library - all of them do *not* implement `Iterator`: `java.text.BreakIterator`, `java.text.CharacterIterator`, `java.text.StringCharacterIterator`, `java.text.CollationElementIterator`, `javax.swing.text.ElementIterator`, `java.awt.geom.java.awt.geom.FlatteningPathIterator`, `java.awt.geom.PathIterator`, `org.w3c.dom.traversal.NodeIterator`.

Comment: @HonzaZidek i looked at your examples. Iterator was introduced in javase 1.2. your examples dont even include a "since" section, which lets me assume they are from a time when "since" was not used.

Comment: @LonelyNeuron You might be right - however I still do not mind calling my class `XxxIterator`. It should probably have been `ClassHierarchyIterator`. **Internal iteration** is a new concept in Java, so that the Java programmers are not used to it yet.

Comment: @HonzaZidek how is iternal iteration being new a reason to stick with the name? also, internal iteration has always been used, only not at the scale we use it since java 8

Comment: @LonelyNeuron I understand your point and I understand why you may not like the name. Still I have not found any name which would grasp the purpose of the class better. In my opinion the class *is* an iterator for class hierarchy. An *internal* iterator. The functional approach is not conceptually compatible with the `hasNext() - next()` like style but still it is an iterator.

Comment: @HonzaZidek You don't need to think of a good name, because it doesn't encapsulate any functionality. You can make all methods static, so it is really nothing but a utility class

Comment: @LonelyNeuron Well, I strongly disagree with all the opinions you expressed in your last comment. 1. I believe we **always** should think about a good name. 2. I would **never** make this methods static, but used either the singleton pattern or better CDI/IoC. 3. Utility class is generally an antipattern - and **whenever** it is easy to avoid without making the code more complicated, I simply avoid it.

Comment: @HonzaZidek Yes, utility classes are an antipattern, but try to remind yourself *why* they are an antipatzern. you did in fact create a utility class, you just didn't make the mrthod static (which is the worst of both worlds). your class doesn't inherit anything. It would never make sense to pass it as a parameter. No other class would have this class a private member. So your class doesn't follow the principle of object oriented programming. Really that one function *should* be static, as there is no reason to not make it static.

Comment: The only way to give this class a reason not to be a utility class would be to have it implement a `BiConsumer` or something like that. But even that would be artificial as I can't really think of a scenario where you would actually pass this to a `Stream`. And @1 (because I didn't address it yet) yes, we always need good naming. What I meant was that you could just move the method to a some Utility class, renderin the class name irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick Breadth First Hierarchy transverse:

```
public class ClassHierarchy {
    private Queue<Class<?>> queue;
    //a collection of "visited" classes,
    //which is also the result of the search
    private Set<Class<?>> visited;

    public Set<Class<?>> getClassHierarchy(Class<?> cls){
        visited = new LinkedHashSet<>(); //initialize visited log
        bfs(cls);
        return visited;
    }

    //breadth first traverse on hierarchy
    private void bfs(Class<?> cls) {

        if(cls == null){ return; }
        queue = new LinkedList<>(); //initialize queue
        queue.add(cls);
        while (! queue.isEmpty()) {
           cls = queue.poll();
           //loop over super classes
           for(Class<?> nextClass : getSuperClasses(cls)){
                if((nextClass != null) &&  visited.add(nextClass)) {
                     queue.add(nextClass); //add class to the queue
                }
           }
        }
        return;
    }

    private List<Class<?>> getSuperClasses(Class<?> cls) {
         List<Class<?>> superCs = new ArrayList<>();
         superCs.addAll(Arrays.asList(cls.getInterfaces()));
         superCs.add(cls.getSuperclass());
         return superCs;
    }

    private boolean isVisited(Class<?> cls) {
        return !(visited.add(cls));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassHierarchy ch = new ClassHierarchy();
        System.out.println(ch.getClassHierarchy(LinkedList.class));
    }
}
```

(Please check carefully. I did not have time yet to debug and improve. Will look at it later)

Comment: isVisited() method can be simplified to `return !(visited.add(cls))` 

Comment: My very first solution (before the `Iterator<Class?>>` one) looked something like this ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution without external libraries, but which still works lazily and visits every class exactly once:

```
public static Iterable<Class<?>> getClassHierarchy(Class<?> baseClass) {

    return () -> new Iterator<Class<?>>() {

        private Class<?> nextValue;
        private Queue<Class<?>> remaining = new LinkedList<>(Collections.singleton(baseClass));
        private Set<Class<?>> visited = new HashSet<>();


        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            while (nextValue == null && !remaining.isEmpty()) {
                Optional.ofNullable(remaining.poll())
                        .ifPresent((Class<?> type) -> {
                            visited.add(type);
                            Stream.concat(
                                streamOptional(Optional.ofNullable(type.getSuperclass())),
                                Arrays.stream(type.getInterfaces())
                            ).filter(visited::add)
                             .forEach(remaining::offer);
                            nextValue = type;
                        });
            }
            return nextValue != null;
        }

        private <T> Stream<T> streamOptional(final Optional<T> optional) {
            return optional.map(Stream::of).orElse(Stream.empty());
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> next() {
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            Class<?> value = this.nextValue;
            this.nextValue = null;
            return value;
        }
    };

}
```

Note: writing this was a pain (in Java 8), because unfortunately, there is no `Optional.stream()` method and `Stream.generate(supplier)` can't be terminated so I couldn't use it.

Comment: nice solution! very Java-8-ish